# java get absolutepath given subfolder

Tags: java, file, filepath

I have researched this but cannot find a concise way to find the root or absolute path given the partial path in java.
For example given:

```
../enterprise/production/bin/
```

I need to find the absolutepath as it is not a given that the files are stored on default c drive and no explicit file name can be used.

```
File directory= new File("..\\enterprise\\production\\bin");
directory = Paths.get("..\\enterprise\\production\\bin").toFile();
```

The above doesn't work. Any ideas? I realize this may be trivial but just cannot think of a quick way to do this.

Comment: oh duh. Sorry about that; just realized after posting.

Comment: Actually that's not a great answer as it won't resolve special path fragments such as `.` and `..`, looks like it just prepends the current working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually works for me:

```
    File directory= new File("\\enterprise\\production\\bin");
    String dpath = directory.getAbsolutePath();
    dpath = dpath + "\\Temp\\";
    File ndirectory = new File(dpath);
```

Comment: Sorry I told you to use `getAbsolutePath`, that was just plain wrong. You want to use [`File.getCanonicalPath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath\(\)) instead which will resolve special path fragments such as `.` and `..`

Comment: thats fine I appreciate your response. will try that too.

Comment: I will delete this post after a while if the negative vote stays or you can post the answer and I will accept yours

Comment: If you update your answer to use `getCanonicalPath` (after trying it though, don't fall for trusting me twice :p) you'll get my upvote, it's easier than updating my deleted answer ;)